# Determining weights for fitting non-uniformly spaced measured data (v2)

Tags: regression, weighted-regression, weights

Let's pretend I have some data to which I want to fit a line.  If the data are uniformly spaced along the x-axis, I get the following:

[image]

If the data are not uniformly spaced, I get a different fit line:

[image]

Is there a method to adjust the weights for each of the points based on their distribution along the x-axis, so that I could get a fit line from non-uniformly spaced data that is the same as for uniformly spaced data?

Please note: That this is an artificial example.  The question is not about finding a better model for this data.

Comment: I have some trouble understanding what you're asking: 1) These lines barely differ, and if they do, they don't significantly. 2) Why should the lines be the same? Did you not fit them on different data? There is a random component to a linear model, so every sample will produce a slightly different regression line. 3) The relationship appears to plateau, are you sure a linear relationship is appropriate?

Comment: My apologies, I'm apparently not good at formulating questions.  Please take it for given that: 1) the difference is significant  2) the lines should be the same and there is no random component. 3) Linear is not the best model for this data.  My question is about fitting a given model, not looking for the best model.

Comment: Your second image has two data points near x=6, with one data point each near x values of 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. Could you also take one additional measurement at each of those x values? That should at least mitigate the problem.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Yes, this would be equivalent to doubling the weights associated with each of those points.  The question is, how do I determine those weights more generally?